# Slider has quit working after PHP upgrade & Joomla migration?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, joomla3.0

My slideshow/banner has quit moving through the images, the page can be viewed here:

http://marionphysicianassociates.com/

It was working until very recently, I'm not sure if the culprit was a recent Joomla! migration, or if it was due to me updating the PHP version to 5.4.29. I will admit I'm not the greatest with PHP, but as mentioned it was working before the upgrades. The slider in question is not a installed module/plugin, but rather it is hard coded into the template (I took this over from someone).

Comment: I see that my "js" folder was renamed to "javascript" with the migration, so I updated that but the slider still won't work. How are you getting those Failure messages? I don't know how to do that and it looks like something I need to learn as well!

Comment: F12 on Chrome Browser opens console and you can see errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have deleted two js files that your template needs:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://marionphysicianassociates.com/templates/mpa/js/js.js

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://marionphysicianassociates.com/templates/mpa/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js
```

Comment: jQuery being removed doesn't matter as it's already being imported from the core as it should be. But yes, you're right about the other .js file

Comment: `jquery` is required for the rest of your slider code. U can  check the console errors if you wont include it.

Comment: Yup, along with removing the file, the reference needs to be removed too. This is another situation where the developer has imported jQuery with their extension incorrectly. Shame devs are still doing this

Comment: U can always include `http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js` so you wont have any problem with updates (between jquery versions)

Comment: For Joomla 2.5, yes, then can be done. But for Joomla 3.x, jQuery is shipped with the library and there are proper methods for importing jQuery. If everything used the same methods on all extensions and templates, then there would never be multiple jQuery libraries being imported :) See my answer regarding jQuery for another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla

Comment: True @Lodder. The whole thing with Jquery versions is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John Priestakos, that was definitely the first issue that needed to be corrected!

After fixing that part, I ended up finding the exact situation and answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20791074/3729322

It turns out the migration caused a jQuery conflict, but as stated this other post answered the question wonderfully.

Comment: You're including jQuery twice ?